# Prove that Petersen's graph is non-planar using Euler's formula

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, eulerian-path

Prove that Petersen's graph is non-planar using Euler's formula. 
I know that $n - m + f = 2$. But should I count $f$ and prove that the summation does not equal to two or solve to get $f =7$ and argue that it is impossible???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using your notation, we have that $n=10$, $m=15$.  Inspecting the graph, we see that (1) each edge is included in exactly two faces, and (2) each cycle has a length of 5 or greater.  Combining these two facts yields $5f \le 2m.$  Substituting this into Euler's formula, we obtain a contradiction.

Comment: `each edge is included in exactly two faces` is this common for any graph

Comment: using $5f \ge 2m.$ we get `f>=6`.Using Euler's formula f=7.So how is it become a contraadiction? I think it should be like this.Deg sum of faces can be >=5f. But degree sum of faces =2m.Thus $2m \ge 5f$.I think your inequality should change sides

Comment: No, there exist graphs where edges are included in exactly one face: consider any tree.  You're correct that the inequality I have should be switched, though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

We know the Petersen graph has $15$ edges and $10$ vertices.  In a planar graph, $V+F-E=2$.  In Petersen, that would be $10+F-15 = 2$, so it would have $7$ faces in it's planar embedding. The minimal cycle in Petersen is $5$, so it would need to be made from pentagons, hexagons, or larger.

$7$ pentagons = $35$ edges or more.  Half that, rounded down = $17$ edges. Each edge can only be used twice, and we've gone over.

Comment: Is it 17 edges or faces?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the definition of planar graph, you can "contract" edges just to get $ K_5 $ or $ K_{3,3} $ and there you prooved that Petersen's graph is non-planar.